# How can we prove that f is an injection when A,B are subsets of Domn(f) and f(A $\cap$ B)=f(A) $\cap$ f(B)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given to prove that $f$ is an injection iff when 
$A,B$ are subsets of $Domain(f)$ then $f(A \cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B).$

I was able to prove that $f(A \cap B)=f(A) \cap f(B)$ when $f$ is an injection. I want to solve the converse now.

Comment: $A, B$ are arbitrary?

Comment: Yes. They are arbitrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x) = f(y) = b$, for $x \neq y$. Then set $A = \{x\}$, $B = \{y\}$. $f[A \cap B] = f[\emptyset] = \emptyset$, while $f[A] \cap f[B] = \{b\} \neq \emptyset$. So if $f$ is not injective, it does not satisfy the property for all subsets of the domain. So $f$ must be injective.

Answer (score 0):

For the converse, Let 
$A=\{x\},\; B=\{y\}$
and 
$f(x)=f(y)\;\forall x,y\in Domain(f).  $
I think it does work.